# Make title bar collapse when scrolling

Tags: menus, themes

Is it possible to make the title bar when scrolling so that it does not take so much of the text space? Right now it looks like this:

[image]

I would like to make the middle bar that says "Berthelot23" collapse when scrolling down, leaving only the navigation bar and the WP menu.

I am using the "Malina" theme.

Answer (score -1):

Malina is a Premium ThemeForest theme, have not used but can give you an overview. Hope this helps.

Most of the premium ThemeForest themes come with Theme setting which you can find under Appearance -> Themes -> Theme setting.

- There are multiple options for choosing a header with the layout we
  want.  You can choose some things from there.
- There can also be a possibility of having different layouts for logos
  and menus.
- You can also write your custom CSS if any of the above doesn't work,
  there must be a feature for adding custom CSS.